# Change background color on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I change the backgraound colour to a solid colour, when I scroll? The color change must trigger when the user scolls in a smooth transition.

http://jsfiddle.net/6ranX/

```
<div class="sticky-nav">
</div>
```

```
.sticky-nav{
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.4)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0,0,0,0)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
```

Comment: please check this one http://jsfiddle.net/vilaskumkar/Uua6M/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery you can trigger a class change on document scroll and change the color according to that class in CSS like this :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/6ranX/1/)**

*jQuery :*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $('.sticky-nav').addClass('scrolled');
    });
});
```

*CSS :*

```
.sticky-nav.scrolled{
    background: gold;
}
```

Comment: Thats nice, but i want that the change starts no inmediatly, i want that starts when i had scroll 100px (for example) and that the change be smooth, like a fade. But thanks!

Comment: @MarkLenders it would have bee nice to explain that in the question... but take a look at this : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/6ranX/3/

Comment: Thanks @web-tiki , but when I start to scroll, there is a flash while the color is changing, how can i solve thiS?

Answer (score 1):

Simply create two CSS classes. One for a solid background colour and one for a gradient. Then use the jQuery .scroll() event listener to toggle between the two CSS Classes.

Comment: i want that the change starts no inmediatly, i want that starts when i had scroll 100px (for example) and that the change be smooth, like a fade.

Answer (score 0):

look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/A7NK4/2/) fiddle

in this code you can intercept start and end scroll (using [jquery-throttle-debounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/))

if the scrool is higher than 100px background becomes blue during scroll.

jquery

```
$(window).scroll($.debounce( 250, true, function(){
    $('#scrollMsg').html('SCROLLING');
    var height = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(height  > 100) {
        $('p').addClass('linear');
    }

} ) );
$(window).scroll($.debounce( 250, function(){
    $('#scrollMsg').html('FINISH');
    $('p').removeClass('linear');
} ) );
```

css

```
#scrollMsg{
 position:fixed;
 color: red;
 font-size: 20px; 
    background-color: white!important;
    padding:20px;
}
p{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.4)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0,0,0,0)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#000000', GradientType=0 );
}
.linear{
    background-color:blue;
}
```